Align legend objects on top of each other by color in two rows - ggplot
Right now the legend has a total of 4 rows. I would like the legend to only have two rows, with the top row being the circle indicating the logger data (circles) and the bottom row being the various symbols (instant data). However I want the legend item on the top to be the color matching (same site) as to the one below.

Data
sep_sonde_do <- structure(list(station_name = c("TMDL-Est", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", 
"TMDL-R3", "TMDL-SA", "TMDL-CL", "TMDL-Est", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", 
"TMDL-R3", "TMDL-SA", "TMDL-CL", "TMDL-Est", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", 
"TMDL-R3", "TMDL-SA", "TMDL-CL", "TMDL-Est", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", 
"TMDL-R3", "TMDL-SA", "TMDL-CL", "TMDL-Est", "TMDL-R1", "TMDL-R2", 
"TMDL-R3", "TMDL-SA", "TMDL-CL"), sample_date_time = c("2023-09-15 11:00:00", 
"2023-09-15 11:00:00", "2023-09-15 11:00:00", "2023-09-15 11:00:00", 
"2023-09-15 11:00:00", "2023-09-15 11:00:00", "2023-09-15 11:15:00", 
"2023-09-15 11:15:00", "2023-09-15 11:15:00", "2023-09-15 11:15:00", 
"2023-09-15 11:15:00", "2023-09-15 11:15:00", "2023-09-15 11:30:00", 
"2023-09-15 11:30:00", "2023-09-15 11:30:00", "2023-09-15 11:30:00", 
"2023-09-15 11:30:00", "2023-09-15 11:30:00", "2023-09-15 11:45:00", 
"2023-09-15 11:45:00", "2023-09-15 11:45:00", "2023-09-15 11:45:00", 
"2023-09-15 11:45:00", "2023-09-15 11:45:00", "2023-09-15 12:00:00", 
"2023-09-15 12:00:00", "2023-09-15 12:00:00", "2023-09-15 12:00:00", 
"2023-09-15 12:00:00", "2023-09-15 12:00:00"), parameter = c("Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen"), result = c(17.28, 10.18, 8.71, 8.71, 8.95, 
8.61, 16.72, 10.03, 8.55, 8.55, 8.53, 8.41, 16.48, 9.84, 8.4, 
8.38, 8.17, 8.21, 16.92, 9.72, 8.25, 8.3, 7.85, 8.03, 16.74, 
9.57, 8.05, 8.21, 7.55, 7.85), units = c("mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L"), comments = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), date = c("2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", 
"2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", 
"2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", 
"2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", 
"2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", 
"2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", 
"2023-09-15", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-15"), ym = c("2023-09", 
"2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", 
"2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", 
"2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", 
"2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", 
"2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09")), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")

sep_sonde_do_situ <- structure(list(station_name = c("Instant TMDL-R1", "Instant TMDL-R1", 
"Instant TMDL-R1", "Instant TMDL-R2", "Instant TMDL-R2", "Instant TMDL-R2", 
"Instant TMDL-R3", "Instant TMDL-R3", "Instant TMDL-R3", "Instant TMDL-R4", 
"Instant TMDL-R4", "Instant TMDL-R4", "Instant TMDL-R4", "Instant TMDL-SA", 
"Instant TMDL-SA", "Instant TMDL-SA", "Instant TMDL-CL", "Instant TMDL-CL", 
"Instant TMDL-CL"), sample_date_time = c("2023-09-15 05:51:00", 
"2023-09-22 03:29:00", "2023-09-29 05:09:00", "2023-09-15 05:13:00", 
"2023-09-22 03:07:00", "2023-09-29 04:43:00", "2023-09-15 04:35:00", 
"2023-09-22 02:42:00", "2023-09-29 04:09:00", "2023-09-15 03:45:00", 
"2023-09-29 03:35:00", "2023-10-06 04:21:00", "2023-10-13 03:40:00", 
"2023-09-15 03:15:00", "2023-09-22 02:08:00", "2023-09-29 03:22:00", 
"2023-09-15 02:45:00", "2023-09-22 01:30:00", "2023-09-29 02:49:00"
), parameter = c("Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", 
"Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen", "Dissolved Oxygen"
), result = c(9.45, 9.32, 8.86, 10.11, 10.46, 10.81, 8.86, 9.22, 
9.19, 7.02, 6.05, 7.96, 8.05, 9.28, 9.8, 9.48, 9.35, 10.1, 9.37
), units = c("mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", 
"mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L"), date = c("2023-09-15", 
"2023-09-22", "2023-09-29", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-22", "2023-09-29", 
"2023-09-15", "2023-09-22", "2023-09-29", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-29", 
"2023-10-06", "2023-10-13", "2023-09-15", "2023-09-22", "2023-09-29", 
"2023-09-15", "2023-09-22", "2023-09-29"), ym = c("2023-09", 
"2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", 
"2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-10", "2023-10", 
"2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09", "2023-09"
)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = "data.frame")



Code
sonde_axis_do <- sep_sonde_do %>% 
  select(date) %>% 
  arrange() %>% 
  unique()

annotation_do_sonde <- data.frame(
   x = c("2023-10-10"),
   y = c(7.5),
   label = c("Numeric Target Minimum DO = 7 mg/L")
)


ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    data = sep_sonde_do, aes(
      x = sample_date_time,
      y = result, color = station_name,
      group = station_name
    ),
    size = 0.8, alpha = 0.6
  ) +
  geom_point(data = sep_sonde_do_situ, aes(
    x = sample_date_time, y = result, fill = station_name,
    shape = station_name,
    group = station_name
  ), size = 3) +
  geom_point(
    data = sep_sonde_do_situ, aes(
      x = sample_date_time, y = result,
      shape = station_name,
      group = station_name
    ), size = 3,
    color = "black", alpha = 1
  ) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = c(7), linetype = "solid", color = "black", size = 0.7) +
  geom_text(
    data = annotation_do_sonde, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label),
    size = 1.2, size.unit = "mm"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 22), breaks = seq(0, 22, by = 2),
    expand = c(0, 0)
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    breaks = unique(sep_sonde_do$date),
    labels = unique(sep_sonde_do$date),
    expand = c(0.04, 0.04)
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 20:26) +
  scale_color_viridis(
    labels = \(x) paste0(x, "<span style='color: transparent'> Instant</span>"),
    discrete = TRUE, name = NULL,
    guide = guide_legend(order = 2, override.aes = list(size = 3))
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  labs(title = "September 2023 - Dissolved Oxygen", y = "Dissolved Oxygen (mg/L)") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.box = "vertical",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",

    legend.margin = margin(),

    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.text = ggtext::element_markdown(size = 6.7),
    legend.key.width = unit(0.15, 'cm')
  )


Your variables should be ordered factors so that they can retain the order you need. Then, you can use guide() to set the desired rows, like this: guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 1, override.aes = list(alpha = 1))), or you can set it elsewhere, like in guide_legend() inside your scale_color_viridis.

you can do this with a single guides() in stead of setting the number of columns in each scale
guides(
    shape = guide_legend(ncol = 7, override.aes = list(size = 3)),
    color = guide_legend(ncol = 7, override.aes = list(size = 3)),
  ) +

